# Formatting a Windows 8.1 laptop, will it revert back to the original w8?

Tags: windows

I recently updated my windows 8 laptop to w8.1, now im thinking of formating my laptop to delete and refresh all my files.. im just wondering since it says that it will remove all updates, will it also go back to its original windows 8?

Comment: Yes it will....

Answer (score 0):

I just did the refresh on 3 pc's that had the 8.1 upgrade on them. I was getting ready to sell them, so i did the erase everything and reinstall Windows feature. All 3 of them returned to the 8.1 upgrade. Was kind of strange, as I had never had this happen before. I'm thinking that I refreshed the recovery partition with the new 8.1 on them, that it is the reason it worked this way. Most generally, an erase and reinstall type refresh will revert back to the original setup. I decided to try it though, so right after the upgrade, i erased the original 8 recovery partition, and instilled the new 8.1 version into the recovery partition. I was really shocked that it worked like I had hope. Might be worth looking into.